# Unnecessary deleting elements from dom without making an action on this elements

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const CreateCriteria = () => {

  const [criteria, setCriteria] = useState({})

  const onClose = useCallback((key) => {
    delete criteria[key]
    setCriteria(criteria)
  }, [criteria])

  const onClick = useCallback(() =>{
    const key = Math.random()
    setCriteria({
      ...criteria,
      [key]: <div onClick={() => onClose(key)}>{
        key
      }</div>
    })
  }, [criteria, onClose])


  return (
    <div>
     {
       Object.keys(criteria).map((entity) => criteria[entity])
     }
    <button onClick={onClick}>
      add
    </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CreateCriteria />, rootElement);
```

Imagine that I have this snippet of code. When I click on `add` button I want to get new elements in the `DOM` and in the criteria object. I do it by generating new par ( `key/value` ) in criteria object and then parse this new data in DOM. I do it because I want also to have the opportunity to delete this object from dom by clicking on this object. When I click on elements from last to first ( from below to above), then it works fine, but for example, if I have 3 elements 1,2,3 and I click on 2, then it also delete 3, and I can't find out why does this happen. You can use `CodeSandbox` for checking it :

https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Does it still happen if you take out the random behaviour? What if you avoid mutating the state object?

Comment: setCriteria({ [key]: undefined, ...criteria })  - if you mean something like this, yes it works in the same way

Comment: this is wrong `delete criteria[key]` you should instead make a copy of `criteria` before mutating.

Comment: { [key]: undefined, ...criteria } isn't it a copy ?

Comment: can you check it pls , and send me right answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You did two errors

1. You assidetially created [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) when adding new keys in `creteria` object. This code

   ```
   [key]: <div onClick={() => onClose(key)}>{
       key
   }</div>
   ```

   not only adds `<div>` element to `creteria` object but create closure with function `onClose`. `onClose` in its turn create includes in closure `creteria` object as it is **in time of** adding new key in `creteria` object. So when `onClose` called, it has only keys that was there when new key added. So you see strange behaviour.

   To solve problem I suggest to store only keys in `creteria` object and encapsulate them in `<div>` during render.
2. Another problem pointed in comments. You should create new `creteria` object in `onClose`. Otherwise React will not update `creterai` as it only compares new and old state using `Object.is`

   To solve this, use destruct operator to create new copy of `creteria` object like this

   ```
   const onClose = useCallback((key) => {
       let newCreteria = { ...criteria };
       delete newCreteria[key];
       setCriteria(newCreteria);
   }, [criteria])
   ```

Also `useCallback` is useless. But code works with them in palce.

Working sample is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56693595-6und2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is really awesome explained. I've attached one more answer when I wrapped Object.keys()... in useMemo, I think it is a little bit optimized. If you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

```
const CreateCriteria = () => {
  const [criteria, setCriteria] = useState({});

  const deleteCriteria = useCallback(
    key => {
      const newCreteria = { ...criteria };
      delete newCreteria[key];
      setCriteria(newCreteria);
    },
    [criteria]
  );

  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    const key = Math.random();
    setCriteria({
      ...criteria,
      [key]: null
    });
  }, [criteria]);

  const CriteriaList = useMemo(() => (
    Object.keys(criteria).map(entity => (
      <div key={entity} onClick={() => deleteCriteria(entity)}>
        {entity}
      </div>
    ))
  ), [criteria, deleteCriteria])

  return (
    <div>
      {CriteriaList}
      <button
      onClick={onClick}
      >
        add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```